# C - function pointer types with named parameters

Tags: c, visual-c++, gcc, function-pointers, named-parameters

On **MSVC** and **gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911** the following compiles and runs just fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func(int a, int b){
    return 0;
}

int main(void){
    int (*funcPointer)(int a, int b);

    funcPointer = func;

    printf("funcPointer = %p\n", funcPointer);

    return 0;
}
```

Is such behaviour well-defined, or is it non-standard and it's actually illegal for function pointer types to have named parameters (i.e. names as well as types in their parameter list)?

Comment: On talking about **msvc** and **gcc** (just two implementations) What do you mean with non-standard?  As far as I believe, %p is not a standard format to print pointers (not sure about c99 and behind) Also don't know what do you want to achieve printing the function pointer at all.

Comment: @LuisColorado: no reason really, just for demonstration purposes =)

Comment: yeah, but in that case it's not worth to speak about standard behaviour, as there are as behaviours as implementations.  The majority of implementations use the function call entry point as the pointer to it, so there's no difference in the value stored into the variable once the type checking is done (at compile time)

Comment: @LuisColorado: yes, but the question was about the behaviour of a different part of code. I don't think it's really this important. And anyway, the question's already answered

Comment: Completely in agreement with you but the standard doesn't warrant this works just because one implementation gives the right/expected answer.  Another could print just `%p` or `p` or nothing at all.  (just think on one implementation that doesn't define the `p` format specifier)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have a parameter in your function pointer. It is totally valid. The parameter list matches that of the function being called and the names is just optional.

It can also be written as

```
int (*funcPointer)(int,int);
```

I mean

```
int (*funcPointer)(int a, int b);
```

This is valid and you can verify the same  by calling

```
int res = funcPointer(3,4);
```

and returning

```
int func(int a, int b){
    return a+b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly legal.  The names `a` and `b` in `funcPointer` are not used for anything, but they are permitted.  You could use any (legal) names you want, they don't matter at all.

Answer (score 0):

A question in the answer:

Why does this compile and what does it mean?

```
int func(int a) { return a; }

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int(*a)(int x(float)) = func;

    printf("%d\n", a(1));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not valid code.  You are declaring `a` as a pointer to a function with different interface than the one you use to initialize.  You get a warning in C (an error in C++) as pointers are not compatible.  You are passing an `int` instead of a pointer to function that gets a `float` and returns an `int`, but the compiler will call it without check because you have call a variadic function.  It probably print `1`, but the behaviour must be considered undefined by the language definition.